# Install Webkit for Standalone HTML Desktop App

Tags: python, linux, webkit, ubuntu-12.04, pygtk

A few months ago I converted my web application to run as a linux app (kind of, it's just in a web browser to give the illusion that it's a full fledged linux app)

I made it on Ubuntu 14.04 and now I'm using Elementary OS "Luna". It comes preloaded with the Midori web browser that runs off of webkit. I also use Chromium on a daily basis.

```
michael@michael-1619048:~/Documents/My_Sites/MMD/mmd-linux$ ./app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./app.py", line 3, in <module>
    import webkit, gtk, os
ImportError: No module named webkit
michael@michael-1619048:~/Documents/My_Sites/MMD/mmd-linux$ sudo apt-get install webkit
[sudo] password for michael: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package webkit
```

I installed the `libwebkitgtk-dev` dependency (which also had me install a stack of other ones, list below.

```
build-essential debhelper dh-apparmor dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-4.6
  gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-1.0
  gir1.2-webkit-1.0 html2text intltool-debian libalgorithm-diff-perl
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libatk1.0-0
  libatk1.0-data libatk1.0-dev libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2-dev
  libdpkg-perl libexpat1-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev
  libgail-common libgail18 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-dev libgtk2.0-0
  libgtk2.0-dev libice-dev libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-dev libmail-sendmail-perl
  libpango1.0-dev libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0 libpixman-1-0 libpixman-1-dev
  libpng12-dev libpthread-stubs0 libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev
  libsoup2.4-dev libstdc++6-4.6-dev libsys-hostname-long-perl libx11-6
  libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev
  libxcb1-dev libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev
  libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxfixes3 libxft-dev libxi-dev libxi6
  libxinerama-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libxml2-utils libxrandr-dev
  libxrender-dev po-debconf x11proto-composite-dev x11proto-core-dev
  x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev
  x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-render-dev x11proto-xext-dev
  x11proto-xinerama-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev zlib1g-dev
Suggested packages:
  dh-make debian-keyring g++-multilib g++-4.6-multilib gcc-4.6-doc
  libstdc++6-4.6-dbg libcairo2-doc libglib2.0-doc libgtk2.0-doc
  libpango1.0-doc libsoup2.4-doc libstdc++6-4.6-doc libxcb-doc
  libmail-box-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  build-essential debhelper dh-apparmor dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-4.6
  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-1.0 gir1.2-webkit-1.0 html2text intltool-debian
  libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl
  libatk1.0-dev libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2-dev libdpkg-perl
  libexpat1-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev
  libglib2.0-dev libgtk2.0-dev libice-dev libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-dev
  libmail-sendmail-perl libpango1.0-dev libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0
  libpixman-1-dev libpng12-dev libpthread-stubs0 libpthread-stubs0-dev
  libsm-dev libsoup2.4-dev libstdc++6-4.6-dev libsys-hostname-long-perl
  libwebkitgtk-dev libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev libxcb-render0-dev
  libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb1-dev libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev
  libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxft-dev libxi-dev libxinerama-dev
  libxml2-dev libxml2-utils libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev po-debconf
  x11proto-composite-dev x11proto-core-dev x11proto-damage-dev
  x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev x11proto-randr-dev
  x11proto-render-dev x11proto-xext-dev x11proto-xinerama-dev
  xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev zlib1g-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data
  libgail-common libgail18 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common
  libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libgtk2.0-0 libpixman-1-0 libx11-6 libxfixes3
  libxi6 libxml2
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install python-webkit python-webkit-dev`

Using  `apt-cache search your_package` is handy when you cannot find a package